Scale the size of figure/subfigure
I need to scale the figure to 0.5 of the original size.
Doing \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} shifts the subfigure to the right.
I just need it to be smaller, but remain centered.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt
\font\smallit=cmti10
\font\smalltt=cmtt10
\font\smallrm=cmr9

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem} 

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \vspace{5mm}   
     some text here
       \begin{center}
          \scriptsize
            $$1234$$
       \end{center}       
\end{subfigure}
        
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Use \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure}, rather than setting something in the outer environment.

Your code does not compile successfully for me.  You appear to have omitted to load the package that provides the subfigure environment.

But I do not add graphical files. The subfigures contain tables.

Note that we really have to know what you are loading for subfigure because I seem to remember more than one package defines it.

@Vika: Then use \scalebox{0.5}{<stuff>}.

A subfigure is just a minipage with captions, except you have no captions.

Please, make a sensible example: in the code you showed, figure and subfigure environments are completely unnecessary.
